Determining the correct sample space
A box contain two coins: a regular coin and a fake coin with heads on both side. I choose a coin at random and toss it twice. Define the following events:
A- First coin toss is head
B- Second coin toss is head
C- Coin 1(regular coin) is picked
Find $P(A), P(B), P(A\cap B)$.
I realize that I need to use total probability to solve this, so I need to partition the sample space. To have a result I need to first pick a coin out of the box so then I need to toss it twice, so I think my sample space consist of length 3 list $\{(C,A,B),(C,A,B^c),(C,A^c,B),(C,A^c,B^c), (C^c,A,B)\}$ but with this set up I have no idea on how to proceed. I think the sample space is obviously not correct but I just dont know what other sample space I can have in this case. Could someone me understand. Thanks! once I can build the correct sample space finding the answer should just be applying formulas.

An event is a subset of the sample space. The sample space here is {real coin + flip HH, real coin + flip HT, real coin + flip TH, real coin + flip TT, fake coin + flip HH} (note that not all elements are equally likely).

With this sample space, Event A would be the subset {real coin + flip HH, real coin + flip HT, fake coin + flip HH}. Event B would be the subset {real coin + flip HH, real coin + flip TH, fake coin + flip HH}. Event C would be E - {fake coin + flip HH} (where '-' denotes set-theoretic difference).

If you're wanting to construct an explicit sample space, it can be taken as the set whose elements are the five outcomes listed in the following table:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Outcome}\\ \text{(coin, toss#1, toss#2)} & \text{Probability} & \text{A}  & \text{B}  & \text{C} & \text{A}\,\cap\text{B}\ \\
\hline
\text{(1,H,H)} & {1\over8} & \checkmark& \checkmark & \checkmark&\checkmark\\
\hline
\text{(1,H,T)} & {1\over8} & \checkmark&            &\checkmark\\
\hline
\text{(1,T,H)} & {1\over8} &           &\checkmark & \checkmark\\
\hline
\text{(1,T,T)} & {1\over8} &           &            &\checkmark\\
\hline
\text{(2,H,H)} & {1\over2} & \checkmark & \checkmark &  &\checkmark\\
\hline 
               &           & {3\over4} &{3\over4}& {1\over2} & {5\over8}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
The coin is chosen "at random", so the event consisting of the first four outcomes and the event consisting of the last outcome must be equally likely events; i.e. each of those two events has probability ${1\over2}$. Furthermore, since coin#1 is "fair", each of the first four outcomes must be equally likely, so each has probability ${1\over8}$.

Here is one solution. There are likely many others.
Define a new event as $F$ - the coin chosen is Fake.
Then $P(F)=\frac{1}{2}$.
$P(A)=P(H|F)+P(H|F^c)$
$=P(H\cap F)\times P(F)+P(H\cap F^c)\times P(F^c)$
$=1\times\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}$
$=\frac{3}{4}$
Events $A$ and $B$ have the same probability as the numbering of the coin tosses does not matter (the coins do not remember how they landed in the past) so $P(B)=\frac{3}{4}$ as well.
Now, for a similar reason, $A$ and $B$ are independent events, so $P(A\cap B)=\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{3}{4}=\frac{9}{16}$
